# How to prompt the user to continue?

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application, do-while

I want to ask the user if they want to continue adding two numbers, so if they type `Y` it would start again if `N` it will exit.

I'm not sure if I should use `if`/`else` or `while` (or both!) or something else.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Console.Write("Enter a number to add: ");


int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter another number to add: ");
int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int num3 = num1 + num2;

string num11 = Convert.ToString(num1);
string num22 = Convert.ToString(num2);

Console.WriteLine(" " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + num3);
Console.Write("Do You want to add more numbers? Y / N");

Console.ReadLine();
```

How can I finish it?

Comment: You need a loop.  Which one is not too important.  You can do `while(1)` to loop forever, and then `if( Console.ReadLine() == "N" ) { break; }`.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's extract method `ReadInt` (why should you *repeat yourself?*):

```
private static int ReadInt(string title) {
  // keep asking user until correct value provided
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    // If we can parse user input as integer...
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
      return result; // .. we return it

    Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Please, try again"); 
  }
}
```

**Main code:** Here, you can wrap the code fragment into `do {...} while` (since you want the loop to be performed at least *once*)

```
do {
  int num1 = ReadInt("Enter a number to add: ");
  int num2 = ReadInt("Enter another number to add: ");
        
  // (long) num1 - we prevent integer overflow (if num1 and num2 are large)
  Console.WriteLine($" {num1} + {num2} = {(long)num1 + num2}");

  Console.WriteLine("Do You want to add more numbers? Y / N");
}
while(Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
```

Comment: +1 for extracting the method and keeping it DRY. However, shouldn't the `while` portion of your `do {...} while` simply be `while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y);`?

Comment: @The2Step: IMHO we have a typical `do {..} while()`: we want loop be performed *at least once*. Please, note, that `while() {...}` can be not executed at all.

Comment: Sorry I think I misspoke, I agree with your use of the `do {...} while` in this case. However, I am referring to the error it throws in the `while` portion. You are calling `Console.ReadKey` twice, and I was saying I believe it should rather be `(Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y)`.

Comment: @The2Step: I see! My bad, you are quite right, I've edited the answer

Comment: thanks everyone, it works well. i'm just wondering how these lines work. i though you needed Console.Write() to get text on the screen?  int num1 = ReadInt("Enter a number to add: ");
  int num2 = ReadInt("Enter another number to add: ");

Comment: @zZephyrouSs: we call it *incapsulation*: we put `int num1 = ReadInt("Enter a number to add: ");` and it's `ReadInt` which do all required `Console.WriteLine(...)` (or `Console.Write`). Try changing `Console.WriteLine(title);` to `Console.Write(title);` within `ReadInt` if you prefer such kind of UI

Comment: ok thanks, that seems like it can save some work

Answer (score 1):

```
  while (true)
  {
    Console.Write("Enter a number to add: ");


    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter another number to add: ");
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int num3 = num1 + num2;

    string num11 = Convert.ToString(num1);
    string num22 = Convert.ToString(num2);

    Console.WriteLine(" " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + num3);


    Console.WriteLine("Do You want to add more numbers? Y / N");

    string YesOrNo = Console.ReadLine();

    if (YesOrNo == "N")
    {
      break;
    }
  }
```

You need a loop the most common that I see for a scenario like this is the while loop. You also however need a break condition so that the while loop ends an if statement is one way you could break out like in my example above. The break is reached if the user enters N into the console.

Note my example will continue to run if anything other than N is typed into the console.